# How to check for StrongBox Keymaster hardware availability before key generation?

Tags: android, android-hardware

I am looking for a solution where I can use StrongBox hardware if present in the device to store my cryptographic keys. Currently, I am creating keys having setIsStrongBoxBacked(true) method in KeyGenParameterSpec builder, and when the  StrongBoxUnavailableException occurs I fallback to generate keys without it.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can check whether the device has feature of "PackageManager.FEATURE_STRONGBOX_KEYSTORE" like this:

```
boolean hasStrongBox() {
       return mActivity.getPackageManager()
           .hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_STRONGBOX_KEYSTORE)
}
```

or

```
boolean hasStrongBox;
hasStrongBox = getContext().getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_STRONGBOX_KEYSTORE);
```